# List of dates where Boolean toggles from false to true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   bcc
Date                            
2018-01-02  2695.889893 2682.360107 2683.729980 2695.810059 3367250000  2695.810059 False
2018-01-03  2714.370117 2697.770020 2697.850098 2713.060059 3538660000  2713.060059 False
2018-01-04  2729.290039 2719.070068 2719.310059 2723.989990 3695260000  2723.989990 False
2018-01-05  2743.449951 2727.919922 2731.330078 2743.149902 3236620000  2743.149902 False
2018-01-08  2748.510010 2737.600098 2742.669922 2747.709961 3242650000  2747.709961 True
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-04-13  2782.459961 2721.169922 2782.459961 2761.629883 5274310000  2761.629883 False
2020-04-14  2851.850098 2805.100098 2805.100098 2846.060059 5567400000  2846.060059 False
2020-04-15  2801.879883 2761.540039 2795.639893 2783.360107 5203390000  2783.360107 False
2020-04-16  2806.510010 2764.320068 2799.340088 2799.550049 5179990000  2799.550049 False
2020-04-17  2879.219971 2830.879883 2842.429932 2874.560059 5792140000  2874.560059 False
577 rows × 7 column
```

How can i get list of dates where in the columns `bcc` boolean `False` toggled changed to `True`. For example in the `data` i have posed above you can see on `2018-1-08` was the date where `False` toggled to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain 2 mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`, for second mask is used [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with inverted mask by `~` for select by False values:

```
df2 = df[df['bcc'] & (~df['bcc']).shift(fill_value=False)]
#~ working like
#df2 = df[df['bcc'] & (df['bcc'] == False).shift(fill_value=False)]
print (df2)
                  High          Low         Open        Close      Volume  \
Date                                                                        
2018-01-08  2748.51001  2737.600098  2742.669922  2747.709961  3242650000   

              Adj Close   bcc  
Date                           
2018-01-08  2747.709961  True
```

Comment: I changed the question to toggle from false to true. So i should get `2018-1-08` as a date.

Comment: Could you please help me with 1 other problem. I need to create a column called 'pct'  in `df2` from data in `df` where i get the previous day's close `/` today's Low where the values are `True` in `bcc`. Could you please help me with this?